# ios6 UIWebview with xcode 4.5 flickers when scrolling the page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, uiwebview, ios6, xcode4.5

This problem is reproducible in ios6 with xcode 4.5. If you load a webpage in a UIWebView which scrolls the window/document after a certain timeout using either jquery scrollTop or window.scrollTo or even by changing the hash of the document, the UIWebView will shows its background momentarily before starting the scroll. Here is a ([JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitinbizsingh/QuLkW/)) that if you open in a UIWebView built with xcode 4.5 will cause the effect described above.

This however does not happen when you scroll a scrollable div.

Has anyone faced this issue with the new xcode? Any suggestions/fixes?